# Получить динамический параметр из запроса на стороне сервера NUXT

Tags: nuxt.js

Всем добра, уважаемое сообщество.
у меня проект на NUXT. Сайт будет работать с запросами из разных городов рф и для каждого города будет отдавать страницу по урл где город будет динамической часть, то есть урл вида http/any.com/_cityName.
Мне нужно на СТОРОНЕ СЕРВЕРА прочитать что в _cityName и подставить это для запроса в апи чтобы получить набор мета тегов для этого конкретного города. Тоесть если запрос на урл http/any.com/moskow то иду за мета информацией для москвы.

Answer (score 0):

Странно но никто так и не накинул вариант. За 2 дня сам нашел решение

```
async fetch() {
    if (this.$route.params.city) this.checkCurrentCity(this.$route.params.city)
    // получение мета инфы по городу
  },
```

Имеем доступ к параметрам роута оттуда вытягиваем динамическую часть и по ней делам все внутри функции фетч которая рабоатет на стороне сервера.